# How to style React class component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I defined `class` component for my form in React but I am getting an error when I want to style it.

In functional component I use `const useStyles = theme => ({})`  and `const classes = useStyles();` to style functional component and it works.

Now I need to style `class` component and I defined `constants` where I put all my style code for the `class` component.

In `class` component element (ex. Box) I use `style` property like :

`<Box style={nameOfTheContant}/>`

and it works.

In my `class` component I need to implement `media queries` and I use `Material UI` breakpoints for that but when I add :

`const classes = useStyles();`

inside `class` component, it does not work.

My goal is to use `media queries` inside `class` component because I need to have special `CSS style` for mobile device. In functional component I use `theme.breakpoints.down["sm"]` but in `class` component it is not possible.

Here is the simplified code:

```
const useStyles = theme => ({
  searchPanel: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor:"red",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      backgroundColor:"green"
    }}});

    export default class SearchPanel extends Component {
          render() {
          const classes = useStyles();
          return (
            <h1 className={classes.searchPanel}>Text</h1>
)}}
```

Comment: It looks like you are mixing some concepts, as you can tell the `useStyles` doesnt work well on a `class` component but why dont you just switch to functional if this is working?

Comment: You aren't returning from useStyles(), also it's a function no need to make it a const. I also don't see any conditional code using "theme" argument within useStyles. also you don't need parens around the arrow function body. plus className value needs to be a string so convert your JSON to a string before returning it

Answer (score 1):

you can use withStyles when styling class components:

```js
// your typical imports here ...
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  searchPanel: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor:"red",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      backgroundColor:"green"
    }
  }
});

class SearchPanel extends Component {
  render() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (<h1 className={classes.searchPanel}>Text</h1>));
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SearchPanel);
```